# Another MVVM Visibility property that's not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-8.1

I'm going crazy about this bug so I really need help.

Upon catching an exception, I'm supposed to show a "message box" (using a grid) that contains a grid, but after explicitly setting the data context to the grid, still it doesn't show me the message box.

XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridBackground" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"  Visibility="{Binding BackgroundVisibility}" Background="#FFB4B4B4" Opacity="0.7"></Grid>

<Grid x:Name="gridWarningMessages" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="200" MaxWidth="600" MaxHeight="600" Visibility="{Binding WarningMessagesVisibility}">
     <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="50" FontSize="29.333" TextAlignment="Center" x:Name="txtWarningMessages" Text="{Binding WarningOrErrorMessage}" FontFamily="Assets/helvetica-neue-thin-1361522098.ttf#HelveticaNeue"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel properties:

```
    private string warningOrErrorMessage;
    public string WarningOrErrorMessage
    {
        get { return warningOrErrorMessage; }
        set
        {
            if (warningOrErrorMessage != value)
            {
                warningOrErrorMessage = value;
                Notify("WarningOrErrorMessage");
            }
        }
    }

    private Visibility warningMessagesVisibility;
    public Visibility WarningMessagesVisibility
    {
        get { return warningMessagesVisibility; }
        set
        {
            if (warningMessagesVisibility != value)
            {
                warningMessagesVisibility = value;
                Notify("WarningMessagesVisibility");
            }
        }
    }

    private Visibility backgroundVisibility;
    public Visibility BackgroundVisibility
    {
        get { return backgroundVisibility; }
        set
        {
            if (backgroundVisibility != value)
            {
                backgroundVisibility = value;
                Notify("BackgroundVisibility");
            }
        }
    }
```

The code that explicitly sets the datacontext to the grid, and 'hides' them upon initialization of the page:

```
var context = (SubmittedOrdersViewModel)DataContext;
gridWarningMessages.DataContext = context;
gridBackground.DataContext = context;
context.BackgroundVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
context.WarningMessagesVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

The code (in the viewmodel, through ICommand..) that's supposed to show the grid after an exception is caught (notice the commented 'Notify' lines, i've tried explicitly firing the Notify after setting a value on the property but still has the same problem):

```
    private void deleteSelectedOrder(object param)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("");

            //working code to delete the order goes here
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            WarningOrErrorMessage = "An error occurred while trying to delete this order.";
            Notify("WarningOrErrorMessage");

            BackgroundVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //Notify("BackgroundVisibility");

            WarningMessagesVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //Notify("WarningMessagesVisibility");
        }
    }
```

Please, please help me. :( Thank you!

Comment: Instead of binding to a visibility variable, bind to a boolean then use a boolean visibility converter

Comment: can't replicate the problem. Your code is working fine here (tested with code-behind as DataContext instead of `SubmittedOrdersViewModel`). and explicitly setting DataContext for both grids seems useless, should've inherited parent's DataContext by default.

Comment: what you need to check is the binding , either supply some dummyconverter to debug threw , or debug the get{} of your property after calling Notify , or use Snoop and check for any binding errors .

Comment: Your `gridWarningMessages` seems to be child of another grid yet now `Grid.Row` nor `Grid.Column` is being set. Is this intentional? Maybe it's being shown, but some other control is overlapping thus making it "invisible"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  just found that there's a piece of code that explicitly sets the visibility property directly on the control's property on page initialization:

```
gridWarningMessages.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
gridBackground.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

So I removed that code and replaced with changing the viewmodel-bound properties instead:

```
context.BackgroundVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
context.WarningMessagesVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

It's now working.

Feel free to comment, WPF experts. Have you encountered such scenarios that explicitly setting the value on the property of the control instead of the viewmodel property messes up the code?

Thanks anyway for those who took time to review my code.